# showing syntax error, unexpected ' please can any one know why this error?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, error-handling

```
function multiform_test_menu() {
  return array(
    'multiform_test' => array(
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'page callback' => 'multiform_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array(array('multiform_test1'), array('multiform_test2')),
    )
  )
}
```

showing

> syntax error, unexpected '

please can any one know why this error??

Comment: isn't `MENU_CALLBACK` a string ? add quotes around it... Also missing a `;` after the last `)`...

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiform_test_menu(){
  return array(
    'multiform_test' => array(
        'access_callback'   => TRUE,
        'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page_callback'     => 'multiform_get_form',
        'page_arguments'    => array(array('multiform_test1'), array('multiform_test2')),
    )
  );
}
```

you need semicolon after `return;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to end `return` with a `semicolon (;)`

function multiform_test_menu() {

```
  return array(
    'multiform_test' => array(
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'page callback' => 'multiform_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array(array('multiform_test1'), array('multiform_test2')),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, the semicolon (;) to close your array is missing :)

```
<?php
function multiform_test_menu()
{
    return [
        'multiform_test' => [
            'access callback' => true,
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
            'page callback' => 'multiform_get_form',
            'page arguments' => [['multiform_test1'], ['multiform_test2']],
        ]
    ];
}
```